# Why don't all heroes in the 1994 Spider-Man cartoon take out the bad guys together?

Tags: marvel, x-men, spider-man

In the second season of the 1994 Spider-Man cartoon series, Spider-Man co-operates with the X-Men. Why is Spider-Man fighting against crime alone? X-Men fought thousands of sentinels and won. They could take out Kingpin like in 5 minutes. Why are the X-Men not helping Spider-Man to take out at least the head of bad guys (Kingpin)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest answer is that whilst Spider-Man *meets* various other heroes throughout the show's six seasons (in crossover episodes), he's always shown a [deep reluctance](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IWorkAlone) to call on them for extra assistance. You might as well ask why he doesn't phone Captain America or Iron Man for help every time some villain beats him up. Heck, Daredevil actually *lives* in New York and still barely gets a mention.

That being said, in the final season during the "[Secret Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Spider-Man_(1994_TV_series)_episodes)" story arc, Spider-Man summons a team of the finest superheroes <s>that aren't on book tours</s> in order to confront a super-villain army that is greater that he can handle. This includes The Fantastic Four, Iron Man, Captain America, and, notably **Storm from the X-Men**.

Comment: They all want to hog the limelight.